# Fetch url parameters in flex web application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I want to fetch some parameters from a url on to my flex web application. How can I do that?

For example I want to fetch the parameters name and age from the url  http://www.abc.com?name=vkwave&age=25 on to my flex application

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var pageURL : String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
var paramPairs : Array = pageURL.split("?")[1].split("&");
for each (var pair : String in paramPairs)
{
    var param : Array = pair.split("=");
    trace("key: " + param[0] + ", value: " + param[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.template.html add an `if` statement betweeen `var flashvars` and `var params`:

```
var flashvars = {};
if (swfobject.getQueryParamValue("name") && swfobject.getQueryParamValue("age"))
{   
    flashvars.name = swfobject.getQueryParamValue("name");
    flashvars.age= swfobject.getQueryParamValue("age");
}
var params = {};
```

In Main.mxml

```
<s:Application ...  creationComplete="init()">

import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

private function init():void {

for (var i:String in FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters) {
    Alert.show( i + ":" + FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters[i] + "\n");
}
```

Will output name:vkwave